# Link to private/shared channels in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams allows to create HTTP-hyperlinks to standard channels.

[image: How to get link to normal channel]

This option is **not** available for private/shared channels. Is it possible to get a link to those channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open private/shared channel in MS Teams.
2. Open `Files`-tab.
3. Click `Open in SharePoint`.
4. Copy link address of `Parent Team` in the side bar on the left.
5. In the link replace `PRIVATECHANNEL` with `TEAMSWEBAPP`.

The link will only work for colleagues that have access to the channel, so those links do **not** compromise security.

Since this is undocumented behaviour relying on internals of Office365, this might stop working with the next Teams/Sharepoint/Office-version.